# How to get access token from HttpContext in .Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to upgrade a project from .Net core 1.1 to .Net core 2.0 there's a lot of breaking changes.

One of the things I'm currently having an issue with is that `HttpContext.Authentication` is now obsolete.

I've been trying to figure out how to get the Access token for the current request.   I need to make a call to another API which requires a bearer token.

**Old Method .Net core 1.1**

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientUpdate(ClientModel client)
{
    var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    return View();
}
```

**Method .Net core 2.0**

This is not working becouse context isnt registered.

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientUpdate(ClientModel client)
{
    var accessToken = await context.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"); 
    return View();
}
```

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext'

I tried registering it but that doesnt work either

```
public ConsoleController(IOptions<ServiceSettings> serviceSettings, HttpContext context)
```

In startup.cs

```
services.TryAddSingleton<HttpContext, HttpContext>();
```

**Update:**

This returns null

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

**Startup.cs  ConfigureServices**

I wouldn't be surprised if it was something in the startup as there were a lot of breaking changes here as well.

```
services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceSettings"));
//services.TryAddSingleton<HttpContext, HttpContext>();
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddMvc();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.ClientId = "testclient";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        });
```

**Startup.cs  Configure**

```
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: You don't have to register `HttpContext`.  It's already available in your controller classes just like in 1.1.

Comment: @Brad thats what i thought but i am not able to access it please describe what you mean.

Comment: Is your controller inheriting from class `Controller`?

Comment: If `GetAccessToken()` returns null it's likely an issue in your authentication config.  How have you configured authentication in Startup?

Comment: ClientUpdate is in the same ConsoleController  so i would have to say yes?

Comment: @Brad that wouldn't surprised me at all.  edit with startup stuff.   I am connecting to a local Identityserver4 project.

Comment: That doesn't show your authentication configuration.

Comment: authentication configuration?

Comment: @DaImTo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971562/how-to-create-project-in-google-console-cloud-platform-using-php-lib-programmati here is my ques, replated to your skills, please ans. i will be thankful to you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It ended up being a configuration issue.   There needs to be a link between AddAuthentication and AddOpenIdConnect in order for it to read the cookie into the headers.

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.ClientId = "testclient";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Add("testapi");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            });
```

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        return View();
    }
```

Access token is now populated.

Note: I ended up digging it out of this project [Startup.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/MvcClient/Startup.cs)

Comment: You don't need `IHttpContextAccessor` in your controller.  It's already there as the `HttpContext` property.

Comment: It was!  Your configuration was incorrect as this answer clearly suggests.  You would have been getting `NullReferenceException` if `HttpContext` wasn't populated.  And this is what i meant by authentication configuration!

Comment: Where did you get `access_token` name? Is it some well-known propertly? Can you please share reference to the docs?

Comment: Yes access token is standard.  Its part of the response.  from authorization.

Answer (score 118):

**.Net core 2.1** 
to access JWT bearer token

```
var accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
```

Comment: How is it possible that my header is empty? It passes my `[Authorize]` Attribute, though... Is it possible that it's in a header called `Cookie`?

Comment: @El Mac apparently, I was missing `options.SaveTokens = true` in the `AddOpenIdConnect` method inside `Startup.ConfigureServices`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50623141/2632991

Comment: @ElMac depends on where you store the token in the request. The token should be in the Authorization header for the above code to work.

Comment: This doesn't return just the token. It also include the auth scheme from the header ("Bearer "), so if you want just the token you have to extract it

Comment: Is there any way to NOT hard-code the `"Authorization"` string? Is that string defined somewhere as a constant or enum?

Comment: @Tobias [Are there any constants for the default HTTP headers?](/questions/11037004/are-there-any-constants-for-the-default-http-headers)

Comment: @WesToleman Great, thanks! I updated the answer to use `HeaderNames.Authorization` instead of the hard-coded string `"Authorization"`.
Unfortunately, in my case this doesn't help because I'd like to use it with an attribute (`[FromHeader(Name = HeaderNames.Authorization)]`) which is not supported because `HeaderNames.Authorization` is not a `const` but a `static readonly`. :-(

Comment: Where does the `Request` come from?

Comment: @Tobias you can use it like this [FromHeader(Name = nameof(HeaderNames.Authorization))] :)

Comment: @EugeneChybisov That would work, yes, but from a design perspective it does not make sense. It just uses the name of the variable instead of its content. It only works because name & content are equal in this case. But you want to use the content here. So I would rather hard-code "Authorization" than to use the variable name of the `Authorization` constant. ;-)

Comment: @manymanymore `Request` is property inside [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.Request?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-5.0) in .NET Core

Answer (score 54):

if you want the pure token this can help you in .net core 3.1

```
var _bearer_token = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
```

and remember you need to add this using

```
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
```

Comment: Very crisp. Wrapping under try...catch would be recommended, optional though.

Comment: Use "HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")" instead.

Answer (score 30):

In Controller, the token can be retrieved by reading `Request.Headers` dictionary:

```
 var accessToken = Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

At other classes where HttpContext is not available, there token can be retrieved using `HttpContextAccessor` after injecting into services collection (
A little change from Azharuddin answer)

Register the service instance in Startup method like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
 ...
}
```

And inject the dependency in your controller like

```
private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
public ClientController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

And retrieve the access token in your action like

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientUpdate(ClientModel client)
{
    var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

    ..........//Some other code
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Startup.cs:**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    ...
     services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    ...
 }
```

**Controller Constructor:**

```
private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
public ClientController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}

[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> ClientUpdate(ClientModel client)
{
    var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    return View();
}
```

This should work

Comment: Works for me with var token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0];
@user1672994 made a small typo Authorziation should be Authorization

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the external schema to retrieve the token.

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, "access_token");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string accessToken = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace($"{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme} ", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Real thanks, this is perfect !

I had this work, but with our azure tenant dedicated authority. Simply replace ****** with your tenant name.

```
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/******.onmicrosoft.com";
```

You also can use tenant id. Simply insert your tenant id after https://login.microsoftonline.com/

```
options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/be0be093-****-****-****-5626e83beefc";
```

Answer (score 0):

My project targeting **.Net 7**

```
string? jwtToken = HttpContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
```

Answer (score -5):

it should be
`HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result.ToString();`

Comment: Blocking an asynchronous method inside an asynchronous action is a very bad idea. It won't fix any namespace issues either.