# WebApi Get access Token from HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth-2.0, .net-core

I'm trying to get the logged in users access token from the HttpContext in my Api  I'm using .Net-Core 2.1 :

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<bool> Test()
{
    var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
    return true;
}
```

**Edit**

I'm using the signing manager to show Auth Providers:

```
SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()
```

And in the External Login Callback I store My tokens with the signin manager like so:

```
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Authentication Configuration is setup like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(COOKIE_AUTH)
    .AddCookie(options => options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60))
    .AddCoinbase(options => {
        options.SendLimitAmount = 1;
        options.SendLimitCurrency = "USD";
        options.SendLimitPeriod = SendLimitPeriod.day;
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Coinbase:ClientSecret"];
        COINBASE_SCOPES.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:coinbase:avatar", "avatar_url");
    });
```

When Even I try to obtain the access token I receive null.  However I can see that i'm logged in from the HttpContext.User.

How do I obtain my access token from the HttpContext?

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49773344/1202807

Comment: @GabrielLuci thanks the addcoinbase method inherits from something similar, the weird thing is I have it working in another project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I use the signin manger to login, It doesn't set the tokens on the HttpContext.  So Instead I get the access token like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<bool> Test()
{
    var userFromManager = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var externalAccessToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(
                                   userFromManager, "Coinbase", "access_token");

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try with this code.

```
HttpContext.Request.Headers["authorization"]
```

Comment: I don't think that is the access token, I think its hidden inside of the cookie some where, but thanks I'll poke around there